# Java - How to set a timeout in an Open API autogenerated RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Using:

- Springboot v2.7.4
- OpenAPI 3.0.3
- org.openapitools.openapi-generator-maven-plugin v5.4.0

With this configuration, I am getting to generate a client to access a Rest API.

I am trying to setup a custom timeout for the autogenerated RestTemplate. I am not finding any documentation with a detailed specification for it.

This is where the Maven plugin is configured:

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${openapi-generator.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>true</skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>
                        <inputSpec>openapi/ability-api.yml</inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                        <library>resttemplate</library>
                        <apiPackage>com.my-org.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>com.my-org.api.dto</modelPackage>
                        <modelNameSuffix>DTO</modelNameSuffix>
                        <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                        <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                        <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                        <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                        <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <configOptions>
                            <java8>true</java8>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            <useTags>true</useTags>
                            <oas3>true</oas3>
                            <useAbstractionForFiles>true</useAbstractionForFiles>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.my-org</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-artifact-id</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Does anyone know where can I find how to do it? Did anyone around face this need?

Comment: The spring boot version is out of date...and end of life (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) furthermore the openapi-generator-maven-plugin version is also out of date (current version 7.3.0)... furthermore the timeout for RestTemplate can be set via builder (a search via your prefered search engine)... would help here..

Comment: You know... sometimes one is constricted to obsolete architectural requirements. That being said, I was all the time looking for automatic configuration (such us setup a custom configuration within the maven generator plugin. But I'll do it using the RestTemplate builder approach. Thanks!

Comment: architectural requirements? It's matter of security etc.